# What is the current `map()` doing?

Tags: gun, gundb

( Gun.version 0.9.6 )

Given the following data structure

```
{
    lights:{
        1:{
            state:{
                on:true,
                color:'red',
                br:254
            }
        },
        2:{
            state:{
                on:true,
                color:'red',
                br:254
            }
        },
        3:{
            state:{
                on:true,
                color:'red',
                br:254
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to turn the lights on/off at the same time.
`gun.get('lights').val(cb)` does give me {1:{...},2:{...},3:{...}} and `gun.get('lights').path('1.state.on').put(false);` works perfect.

I thought that by doing `gun.get('lights').map().path('1.state.on').put(false)` it would 'map' over all lights but instead it only changes the first light.

Question: How do i turn on/off all the lights ?

Comment: Hmm it seems i encountered this 'problem' a long time ago...
If i refresh my browser i can do `gun.get('lights').map().path('state.on').val(cb)`  and it will show me all 'on' values. If i run the same command a seconf time i only get one...
Like i said... we talked about this behavior a long time ago...still i find it very annoying

Answer (score 0):

@stef-de-vries , you've spotted an important TODO bug in gun's source code!

Currently (v0.9.6), `put` does not work with `map()` commands. I think it only picks the first item (which may be random) and then turns it off.

This is bad, and needs to be addressed.

For now, the work around is to probably do something like:

```
gun.get('lights').map().path('state.on').val(function(){
  this.put(false);
});
```

Which is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. okay, but it fails on `gun.get('lights').map().val(cb)`  also if i run it the second time.

Solved my problem with the `each()` module

```
gun.get('lights').each(node=>{
          gun.get(node._['#']).path('state.on').put(true)
        })
```